# Hadoop - Map task 'SUCCEEDED' but Container exited with a non-zero exit code

Tags: hadoop, emr

As you can see, the State is SUCCEEDED but the note says the Container exited with a non 0 status code.

If I check the output of the map task (a particular file needed to be created on S3 after some computation), it seems to have worked well. And the stdout is as expected. The syslog does mention this Container issue -

https://paste.ubuntu.com/15326353/

[image: SUCCEDED Map Task]

Usually this map task would be expected to be run for not more than 1 hour. Here it goes on for ~7 hrs 21 mins and then the container exits but the state is still SUCCEEDED

There are other map tasks which SUCCEEDED with this same message but the time is more reasonable -

[image]

And there are a few which FAILED because of a timeout -

[image]

Any idea how I could debug this further? This is appearing out of the blue, and other jobs with the same parameter do not show such behaviour.

Comment: are there any other jobs that are contending for the resources ? AM kills the containers after they complete the assigned task, which is what you are seeing in the first two cases.

Comment: No, this is the only job running on this cluster. If the Task completes, the containers should exit themselves right? Why would they depend on the AM for killing them?

Comment: What is the state of the map task (not the specific attempt)?  Is there multiple attempts for the same task?